# Why there's an issue in numbers from 101 - 109

Tags: c++

I was typing a c++ task, I am asked to receive a number from `1~999`, then print this number in English i.e. 342 -> Three hundred and Forty Two 
 
I got an issue in numbers from `101` to `109`, it prints some trash words like asdkljaskjjaad meaningless output, and the program stops and sends a message `"main.exe has stopped working."` , Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
string arr [20]= {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten","Eleven","Twelve","Thirteen","Fourteen",
    "Fifteen","Sixteen","Seventeen","Eighteen","Nineteen","Twenty"};
string ar[8] = {"Twenty","Thirty", "Forty", "Fifty", "Sixty","Seventy", "Eighty","Ninety"};

int k, j,trash,rem;

for (int i = 0; i < 999; i++){
    cin >> i;
    if (i <= 20 && i>0){
    cout <<arr[i-1];
    break;
    }
    else if ( i > 20 && i <= 99){
        k = i/10;
        i%=10;
        cout << ar[k-2] <<" " << arr[i-1];

        break;
    }
else if (i > 99 && i <=999){
      k = i /100; // leftmost digit
      j = i / 10; // leftmost digit and second digit
      trash = j % 10; //  the second digit
      rem = i %10;  //  the rightmost digit 

      if (i % 100 == 0){
     cout << arr[k-1] <<   " Hundred";
     break;
      }
     else if (i %10==0 && j!=0){

        cout << arr[k-1] << " Hundred" <<" and " << ar[trash-2];

     break;
     }
    else if (i % 10 !=0 && j ==0){
           // the problem is here 
        cout << arr[k-1] << " Hundred" <<" and " << arr[rem-1];
    break;
    }
    else if (i % 10!=0 && j!=0){

        cout << arr[k-1] << " Hundred " << "and " << ar[trash-2] <<" " << arr[rem-1];
        break;
    }
}
}

}
```

I also forgot to add a case for numbers `110` to `119`, What is the problem here?

Comment: You're probably getting a Segfault by going off the end of an array somewhere. Have you done any debugging?

Comment: Time to start up that program in your debugger and step through line by line. You'll be able to see then, when any variable value isn't changing as you expect it to do.

Comment: Down vote reason?

Comment: Is that the problem?

Comment: @LukeMichaels Likely because you've dumped code with no indication of debugging. Debugging is a necessary skill, and you need to try debugging before posting here, and show your debugging efforts.

Comment: @LukeMichaels Yes, that's a problem.

Comment: @TheDude I use ideone.com an online compiler. I don't have a debugger I'm thankful If you show me a debugger to work with.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I didn't know what debug is.

Comment: You don't need a debugger. Follow the logic of your code for those cases and write down the values of all variables. You will find that you're indexing outside an array.

Comment: @LukeMichaels Here's one: https://www.onlinegdb.com/ Just google, I'm pretty sure there are plenty of them available online.

Comment: You have a loop set for `i`, then you allow to modify the `i` inside this loop with user input and then you allow to modify `i` further by doing some assignment to it? This is seriously asking for trouble.

Comment: @molbdnilo okay consider n = 101 rem = n % 10 , rem = 101 % 10 = 1
and cout << arr[rem-1] = arr[0] !! nothing will be outside the array

Comment: @LukeMichaels why not get a compiler and debugger then? But you can also debug without a debugger. Debugging means troubleshooting, or trying to find out what the problem is. A debugger is very helpful but not always required (it lets you do things like run one statement at a time and check what values are in all your variables).

Comment: The reason people downvoted this question is you're asking them to do *all* the work for you. Instead you should try to find the problem yourself, and *when you get stuck*, then you can ask for help about the part you're stuck on.

Comment: @immibis I added a comment in the code // here is the problem in the fifth if  statement.

Comment: @LukeMichaels okay that's not bad. But do you have any idea what is wrong with the fifth if statement? And are you sure that it's actually running the fifth if statement?

Comment: @immibis yes if i = 101

Comment: @LukeMichaels Debugging is the process of narrowing down a problem to figure out what's causing it. It's a required skill to be a programmer. I highly recommend learning it immediately.

Comment: @TheDude I didn't know the website! Hillarious :-) And it actually contains some pointers on where to start reading about debugging. Live ot!

Comment: @LukeMichaels if you put `cout << "got here" << endl;` in the fifth if statement (before anything else) does it print "got here" before it crashes?

Comment: @immibis it doesn't !

Comment: Why do you think the problem is at the line you indicated? It isn't. (Think harder about the value of `j`.)

Comment: @molbdnilo If you don't say what the problem is, I will write this program again from scratch. I don't know why I used for loop! It's useless.

Comment: @LukeMichaels `j` is `i / 10`. What is `101 / 10`? (Hint: it's not zero.)

Comment: @LukeMichaels So it should print "got here" if the program runs the fifth if statement, right? If it *doesn't* print "got here", what does that tell you?

Comment: I suggest you spend some time trying to figure out the problem instead of just writing the whole program over again and hoping it works that time.

Comment: @immibis The problem is in j yeah I should have used trash instead.

Comment: @LukeMichaels What have you learned about solving problems?

Comment: Debug is very important.

Comment: This would have never happened if you had used variables named "hundreds", "tens", and "ones".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
else if (i % 10 !=0 && j ==0){
           // the problem is here 
        cout << arr[k-1] << " Hundred" <<" and " << arr[rem-1];
```

If i = `101`, j would be `12` so you should:
In all your if statements replace `j` with `trash` so if i is `101`trash would be `0`, hence it will print `One Hundred and One`